# Possibly memory leak in Pyramid on Appengine Flexible with MemoryStore

Tags: google-app-engine, pyramid, app-engine-flexible, google-cloud-memorystore

We're working on migrating our backend from appengine Standard (and the "webapp2" framework) to Flexible using pyramid. We have a proof of concept of sorts running seemingly without many issues. All it does in this early phase is take requests from a third party ("pings") and then go kick off a task to another internal service to go fetch some data. It connects with googles MemoryStore to cache a user-id to indicate that we've already fetched that users data (or attempted to) within the last 6 hours.

Speaking of 6 hours, it seems that every 6 hours or so, memory usage on the Flexible instance seems to reach a tipping point, and then probably flushes, and all is fine again. This instance is set to have 512MB of memory, yet like clockwork it does this at around 800MB (some kind of grace-usage? or maybe these can't be set to under 1GB)

[image: gcp]

It's clear by how gradual it's moving that memory isn't being cleared as often as maybe it should be.
When this happens, latency on the instance also spikes.

[image: gcp2]

I'm not sure what's useful in debugging something like this so I'll try to show what I can.

Appengine YAML file:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: ping
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Dockerfile (as custom-runtime Flexible needs it)

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

RUN virtualenv /env

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

ADD . /app

RUN pip install -e .
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Why custom? I couldn't get this working under the default Python runtime. The `pip install -e .` was what appeared to be needed.

Then, in root `__init__` I have:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from externalping.memcache import CacheStore

cachestore = CacheStore()

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """

    with Configurator(settings=settings) as config:
        config.include('.routes')
        config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Maybe having the connection to MemoryStore defined so early is the issue? Cachestore:

```
class CacheStore(object):
    redis_host = os.environ.get('REDISHOST', 'localhost')
    redis_port = int(os.environ.get('REDISPORT', 6379))
    client = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = redis.StrictRedis(host=self.redis_host, port=self.redis_port)

    def set_json(self, key, value):
        self.client.set(key, json.dumps(value))
        return True

    def get_json(self, key):
        return json.loads(self.client.get(key))
```

On the actual request itself, after importing `from externalping import cachestore`, I'm simply calling those methods shown above: `cachestore.client.get(user['ownerId'])`

This does appear to be how google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex)  says to implement this, as best I can tell. Only difference really is I put a wrapper around it.

Comment: The patterns suggest that a resource gets restarted or flushed every 6 hours. Have you checked appropriate logs? Perhaps you need to add some logging?

Comment: Could you please add the logs happening at the timestamp where the memory graph suddenly decreases? Right now it's hard to tell what might be causing these.

Comment: Believe I've nailed this down to Cloud Tasks, and created an issue here https://github.com/googleapis/python-tasks/issues/20